# RestTemplate Java Spring, no suitable HttpMessageConverter and 422 UnprocessableEntity

Tags: java, spring, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send a message to the Ionic Push API, I've build the Json body correctly, but it says "no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject]".

When I add a HttpMessageConverter I get an 422 UnprocessableEntity back from Ionic.

Here's the code (the code in comment is the MessageConverter):

```
//      MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
//      jsonHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
//      template.getMessageConverters().add(jsonHttpMessageConverter);

        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer <MY API KEY>");
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        String pushMessage = "From : " + notification.getFrom().getNickname() + " Type : " + notification.getNotificationType();
        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray deviceTokens = new JSONArray();
        try {
            deviceTokens.put("DEV-75c960b5-fa90-4da7-b7df-8c1a01f80bdb");
            message.put("message", pushMessage);
            body.put("notification", message);
            body.put("profile", "dev_push");
            body.put("tokens", deviceTokens);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        template.exchange("https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications", HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(body, headers), String.class);
```

From debugging I know that the body of the request matches the structure set up by Ionic

```
{
    "notification": {
            "message":"From : mathijs0032 Type : like"
    },
    "profile": "dev_push",
    "tokens": ["DEV-75c960b5-fa90-4da7-b7df-8c1a01f80bdb"]
}
```

So the problem is probably the HttpMessageConverter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a maven dependency for sending push to GCM (not Ionic Push)

After all my app will use GCM because it's free and separate from the various Ionic Services.

While this is NOT the answer for sending to Ionic API, maybe after somme fiddling you can set the URL to Ionic Push API.

Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
<artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

link to tutorial : http://viveksoni.net/sending-gcm-notification-from-server-spring-framework-java/